# c++: allocating a variable inside a if

Tags: c++, pointers, if-statement, allocation

I am working on some function, this function, depending on some parameters, might need a `Model` object. `Model` objects are quite big and I don't want to allocate one when not needed. Here is, in essence, what I want to do:

```
Model *myModel;
if (modelIsNeeded(arguments)) {
    myModel = &Model(arguments);
}

//processing ...
```

I have the error `error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]`

Do you see any workaround? What is the C++ way of doing what I want to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do you see any workaround? What is the C++ way of doing what I want to do?

Use a [smart pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) instead:

```
std::unique_ptr<Model> myModel;
if (modelIsNeeded(arguments)) {
    myModel = std::make_unique<Model>(arguments);
}
```